# Blender viscosity simulation resetting domain

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation

I made a render of honey using the viscosity [image: Picture of domain being reset]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXtoP.jpg This is the render I did earlier of it and now it has messed up.

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is not answerable at the moment for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Remember only you have access to your scene, so unless you tell us only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Please describe in detail what your issue is, possibly supported by [some accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button under the post. Editing will automatically put it up for review so it can be reopened.